# Histogram of Oriented Gradient

Tags: opencv, histogram

In opencv, I am using HOG for object detection. I want plot the image with gradient plot. Maybe my english is bad so a example image is in the link. I want to plot this type of image. 
http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs143/proj4/

How can i plot this gradient image. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This link might be helpful for you:
http://www.juergenwiki.de/work/wiki/doku.php?id=public:hog_descriptor_computation_and_visualization

But take in consideration that in visualization function he uses constant parameters

```
int blockSize       = 16;
int cellSize        = 8;
int gradientBinSize = 9;
```

also i didn't manage to find out where he uses a **stride** parameter

Comment: Please add content in your answer.